# MySQL world database Trying to avoid subquery

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using the MySQL [WORLD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/world-setup.html) database.

For each Continent, I want to return the Name of the country with the largest population.

I was able to come up with a query that works.  Trying to find another query that uses join only and avoid the subquery.

**Is there a way to write this query using JOIN?**

```
SELECT Continent, Name
FROM Country c1
WHERE Population >= ALL (SELECT Population FROM Country c2 WHERE c1.continent = c2.continent);

+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Continent     | Nanme                                         |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Oceania       | Australia                                    |
| South America | Brazil                                       |
| Asia          | China                                        |
| Africa        | Nigeria                                      |
| Europe        | Russian Federation                           |
| North America | United States                                |
| Antarctica    | Antarctica                                   |
| Antarctica    | Bouvet Island                                |
| Antarctica    | South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands |
| Antarctica    | Heard Island and McDonald Islands            |
| Antarctica    | French Southern territories                  |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.14 sec)
```

Comment: WHERE c1.continent = c2.continent is a join

Comment: I want to rewrite the query to avoid any subquery and use Join only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the "greatest-n-per-group" problem that comes up frequently on StackOverflow.

```
SELECT c1.Continent, c1.Name
FROM Country c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Country c2
  ON (c1.continent = c2.continent AND c1.Population < c2.Population)
WHERE c2.continent IS NULL;
```

Explanation: do a join looking for a country `c2` that has the same continent and a greater population.  If you can't find one (which is indicated by the outer join returning NULL for all columns of `c2`) then `c1` must be the country with the highest population on that continent.

Note that this can find more than one country per continent, if there's a tie for the #1 position.  In other words, there could be two countries for which no third country exists with a greater population.