# mySQL: is this a form of recursion (or co-dependence)?

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have been intrigued by a problem on SQLZoo. It is a "greatest-n-per-group" problem. I would like to understand how the engine is operating.

A table called bbc contains the name, region of the world and population of each country:

bbc( name, region, population)

The given task is to select the most populous country of each region, showing its name, the region and population.

The solution provided is:

```
SELECT region, name, population FROM bbc x
  WHERE population >= ALL
    (SELECT population FROM bbc y
        WHERE y.region=x.region
          AND population>0)
```

**1. Main Question.** I am finding this a bit of a mind twister. I would like to understand how the engine processes this, because at first blush it seems there is some kind of co-dependence (x depending on y, and y depending on x). Does the engine follow some kind of recursion to produce the final selection? Or am I missing something, such that either x or y is actually fixed?

**2. Secondary Question.** Oddly, when I pull the "AND population>0" out of the parenthesis and leave it on its own at the bottom, one of the regions (Europe / Russia) goes missing from the 8 results. Why? I don't understand that.

And indeed, when I try the query on the *world* database (available from the mySQL website on the same page as Sakila), the behavior is different: 
With population > 0 out of the parentheses, I get 6 regions. Six is the right number in this database, because "SELECT continent FROM country GROUP BY continent" reveals seven continents, of which one is Antarctica, which includes 5 "countries", all with a 0 population.

So that seems right.

```
SELECT continent, `name`, population FROM country X
WHERE population >= ALL 
(SELECT population FROM country Y
WHERE Y.`Continent` = X.`Continent`)
AND population>0
```

On the other hand, when I pull "population > 0" back into the parentheses as on SQLZoo, I also get 5 countries with a zero (the countries "belonging to Antarctica"). It doesn't matter if I specify x.population or y.population, I get zeroes.

```
continent      name                                          population  
-------------  --------------------------------------------  ------------
Antarctica     Antarctica                                               0
Antarctica     French Southern territories                              0
Oceania        Australia                                         18886000
South America  Brazil                                           170115000
Antarctica     Bouvet Island                                            0
Asia           China                                           1277558000
Antarctica     Heard Island and McDonald Islands                        0
Africa         Nigeria                                          111506000
Europe         Russian Federation                               146934000
Antarctica     South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands             0
North America  United States                                    278357000
```

Very much looking for insights on these questions!

Wishing you all a beautiful week.

:)

**Notes:**

1. For reference, the problem is number 3a on this page:
   http://old.sqlzoo.net/1a.htm?answer=1
2. A thread mentioning the "greatest-n-per-group" problem for the same query:
   [MySQL world database Trying to avoid subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813580/mysql-world-database-trying-to-avoid-subquery)
3. The world database is available here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Comment: (about Secondary question) What happens if you replace `AND population>0` with `AND population IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: @ypercube, thanks. Yes, that had crossed my mind, and I had tried "AND NOT ISNULL(population)". For the SQLZoo query, same problem (the result set omits Europe / Russia). For the "world" database, same problem (inside the parentheses, we get zeroes).

Comment: I meant to try it in the SQLzoo query, inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Sure, that works IN the parentheses, but so does the "population > 0 version". The question is why "population > 0" (or the notnull() version) fails when it is outside the parentheses.

Comment: It doesn't fail, it produces different results because it is a different query. Inside the parenthesis it means `y.population>0` and rows with NULL population are removed (before the >ALL comparison) while outside it means `x.population>0` so it is checking a different condition (the rows where `y.population` is null are not rejected and thus participate in the `>ALL` comparison.

Comment: You don't need the `x.population IS NULL` outside the parenthesis, it's redundant. If a population is bigger than all other populations in the same region, can it be NULL?

Comment: >can it be NULL? Yes, Antarctica is zero. The point is that it seems to me that the >0 check should work whether it is INSIDE or OUTSIDE the parentheses. 1. Outside the parentheses, SQLZoo version: we lose Russia / Europe. 2. world database version, inside the parentheses: we get the zero rows for Antarctica, regardless of whether we use "AND x.population>0" or "AND y.population>0" or "AND y.population IS NOT NULL" or "AND x.population IS NOT NULL". Sorry, but I don't see how the question has been answered.

Comment: @playful - the only difference in the World one is that there are zeros.  Take a look at the dataset, does it contains for nulls for population? Does it contain zeros?  Take a look and see our answers

Comment: @ypercube, than you very much for your kind and patient explanations. I had a hard time getting it, but I think it is clear now. Wishing you a beautiful week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Main Question. I am finding this a bit of a mind twister. I would like to understand how the engine processes this, because at first
>      blush it seems there is some kind of co-dependence (x depending on y,
>      and y depending on x). Does the engine follow some kind of recursion
>      to produce the final selection? Or am I missing something, such that
>      either x or y is actually fixed?

This isn't recursion. See [this from the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html).  Their solution to the problem is equivalent to this

```
SELECT region, name, population FROM bbc x
  WHERE population = 
    (SELECT max(population) FROM bbc y
        WHERE y.region=x.region
          )
```

> 1. Secondary Question. Oddly, when I pull the "AND population>0" out of the parenthesis and leave it on its own at the bottom, one of the
>      regions (Europe / Russia) goes missing from the 8 results. Why? I
>      don't understand that.

Slight changes (as suggested by ypercube above) work

```
SELECT region, name, population FROM bbc x
  WHERE population >= ALL
    (SELECT population FROM bbc y
        WHERE y.region=x.region
          AND population IS NOT NULL)
```

This query

```
SELECT region, name, population FROM bbc x
  WHERE population is null
```

Returns a row.  Not sure why population should be nullable, but didn't take a good look at the rest of it.  Otherwise, the query should work fine without the `>0`

Also, this is different from the greatest-n-per-group.  In that problem you seek to find the top N items instead of just the top one.

Comment: it's not exactly equivalent to the `MAX` version. Not if there are nulls in there. `MAX()` ignores Nulls. `ALL` does not.

Comment: @dfb, thanks. 1. On your first point, thank you, but my problem is not with the ALL syntax. It is about how the engine deals with these two selections that seem to depend on one another. 2. On the second point, sadly, no, the change suggested by ypercube does not work---the question is what happens if you pull "AND population IS NOT NULL" out of the parentheses. Once again, we are missing the Russia / Europe row.

Comment: @playful - The version I posted above does, I tried it. The problem is that with ALL population>0 returns FALSE for nulls.  Re 1) explain what you mean by 'how the engine deals with' I'm not clear

Comment: @ypercube - Thanks. I changed the wording

Comment: @dfb, no, it does not!!! Once again, the question is about why it doesn't work OUTSIDE the parentheses. I.e, if you want to use IS NOT NULL (same result with population >0), why does "SELECT region, name, population FROM bbc x
  WHERE population >= ALL
    (SELECT population FROM bbc y
        WHERE y.region=x.region
          )
AND population is not null" not work the same? It does not return Europe / Russia.

Comment: And to repeat, the original question #2 with regard to SQLZoo is why "SELECT region, name, population FROM bbc x
  WHERE population >= ALL
    (SELECT population FROM bbc y
        WHERE y.region=x.region
          )
AND population>0" produces a different result. Again, use NOT NULL or not, you will have the same problem.

Comment: @playful - Chill - I just don't understand what you're saying.  The query I gave gives the same results. It doesn't work because of the ALL works - ALL will return false if you don't filter out the NULL values.  If you filter it out afterwards, it's already gone

Comment: @playful - Same thing for the second comment. The whole problem is inside the ALL statement, so if you're filtering afterwards, you've already lost the value.